# What is the default font used in table environment?

Tags: tables, fonts, libertine

I use the following preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=1]{beramono}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
```

I'm pretty new to latex and was wondering whether or not libertine is used in tables? More general, if not told otherwise, is latex just using the main font for tables (and footnotes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever the main font for the document is, will be the font for the table, if the table contains only text. If the table contains things in math mode, then TeX will use the default math font.

Some font packages (like kpfonts, or the combination newpxmath+newpxtext) define math fonts that match the text font. Most others don't, so when you put things in math mode TeX goes back to the default Computer Modern for math symbols.

If you want libertine for both text and math, use this combination:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
```

The libertine option of the newtxmath package will give you a math font designed to match the libertine text font.

See the LaTeX Font Catalogue online for fonts, or font combinations, that have full math coverage.